# Custom, Non-Angular JavaScript in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a few JavaScript files that I need to include in my application, but that are not Angular code. The scripts add functionality for custom modals, an accordion-like element, etc. When writing the JavaScript originally, I used Webpack and `babel-preset-env`.

I copied all the files into my Angular app's `assets` folder, and tried adding it to the `scripts` array in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
...
"scripts": [
    ...
    "assets/scripts/javascript/main.js"
]
...
```

and directly with a `script` tag in the `index.html`.

Neither of these methods seem to work, however. The script is loaded, but there are errors. Like if you try `import {something} from 'file';`, there's an `Unexpected Token` error. Or even if I try `const something = require('file');`, there's a `ReferenceError: require is not defined` error.

What do I need to do to include these scripts in the app?

Comment: Try to use `import something as something from 'file';` or `import * as something from 'file';`, depends on that file content. For example for importing lodash library I use `import * as _ from 'lodash'`.

Comment: `Unexpected token *` error this time. I'm just trying to do this in the script files, by the way. I'm not trying to import them anywhere in the actual Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "Unexpected token" and "require is not defined" errors because you're using either

**a)** ES6 module syntax (`import ...`) or

**b)** CommonJS module syntax (`require()`)

inside your script files, which should be written in plain ES5 Javascript as they will be provided for the browser as is.

You can include all the external `.js` scripts you need to your project by including them all as separate files into the `scripts` array, just make sure they're added in the right order. This is the same as including them as `<script>` tags into your `index.html`.

Check out this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts